# Queries by key and iterating over objects in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

AppEngine docs note that "Queries that return keys are faster and cost less CPU than queries that return full entities."

Which of these two is the more desired way to fetch and iterate over a number of objects from the data store?

```
query_keys = Person.all(keys_only=True)
query_keys.filter('name = ', person_name)
query_keys.order("__key__")

people = db.get(query_keys)                                                
for p in people:
   #read properties of the person object
   print p.name
```

Vs

```
query = Person.all()
query.filter('name = ', person_name)                   
query.order("__key__")

for p in people:
   #read properties of the person object
   print p.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular query performs essentially the operations that your first snippet does, only inside a single RPC. If you need the entities, it's more efficient to just ask for them, than to ask for just the keys and fetch the entities yourself.

One thing you should watch out for efficiency-wise is iterating over Query objects. When you do this, the underlying RPC layer fetches results from the datastore in batches of 20, resulting in a lot of unnecessary RPCs. If you know how many results you need, you should call `fetch()` on the query (like `results = Person.all().filter('name =', 'Joe').fetch(100)`), which will only execute a single RPC.

[Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) is an excellent tool for discovering and diagnosing these sorts of performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

As you're reading full entity **anyway**, then second way will be at least not slower that first one. Probably it will be faster, because it have less api calls

Comment: btw, to get 2 properties from entity, GAE need to load this entity, with all properties, from storage, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

A key-only query gives you keys, not an entity that has properties. In the first example, `p` won't have a `.name`. Also, key order is implicit. If you want properties from an entity, a key-only query isn't what you want; you're going to have to query for the entity. There's no way at present to get less than all properties, so factor that in to your data modeling.

Here's third alternative, which you may or may not find more readable. It'll perform equivalently to your second fragment.

```
people = Person.gql("WHERE name=:1", person_name)
for person in people:
    print person.name
```

Whether you use this approach or your second snippet, querying directly for entities is going to be faster than querying for their keys, and then fetching the entities that correspond to those keys.

Comment: `p` will have a name, because it's an element of `people`, which he fetched using `db.get`.

Comment: Line 5. He fetches the entities corresponding to the keys, then iterates over those.

Comment: `get()` works on any list or iterable - and a query is an iterable.